# Cluster symbol based on colour and value in another field

Tags: qgis, symbology, clustering

In a group of points where i am using the cluster symbol to indicate the number of close points, I would instead like to have the value from another field as the display number.  For example points A1-A6 have the same lat/long, and the cluster symbol would display say the number 6.

If it can display the sum of the frequency column (i.e. 13) instead, what would I type in the font marker the expression string builder to achieve this?

[image: Table example]

Answer (score 5):

The [`sum()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#sum)-function does exactly what you need.

It sums up any expression, if needed grouped and/or filtered for additional conditions.

Basically you'd use `sum("Freq")` - this returns the total sum of the column `"Freq"`. This can be grouped by an additional expression. If you had a separate column for your group, you simply hand over that column, e.g. `sum("Freq","groupfieldname")`.

Since your group-designations are only part of your feature-IDs, you need to extract the group first. Assuming that your groups only run from `A` through `Z`, you can use `left("Point",1)` - this returns a string with the length of one character counted from the left of your feature-ID.

Mash it together:

`sum("Freq",left("Point",1))`

Now you get the sums of you `"Freq"`-field grouped by their ... well... group.

Comment: Erik, If i used sum("Freq") it returns the sum of the whole Freq column, not the clustered points.

Comment: I suggest you read the whole answer, thank you @user16812309.

Comment: Thankyou Erik, I have followed through with grouping my points and your answer works well for some points, but some others weirdly have a incorrect number.  For example, where two points cluster and one has an sum value of 10, some show the correct amount, but another will show a sum value of 18046.  Im still working on it.

Comment: Please provide example data of a faulty group @user16812309

Comment: Erik, issue resolved by checking the data.  In cells where there was a 'null', for freq instead of a number, the sum would be weird. Removing the nulls solved the issue.  The nulls should have been a 1 anyway.  THankyou.  I hate qgis a bit less today.